# What kind of connector is this, where can I get one, and how do I attach it?

Tags: connector, identification, fan

I have to replace a fan in an older (circa 2010) NAS storage device, and I found a replacement but the wires don't terminate in a connector (see first image below):

[image: unterminated wires from new fan]

The old connector looks like this:

[image: connector image 1]
[image: connector image 2]

What kind of connector is this, where can I get one (for as cheaply as possible), and how do I connect the unterminated wires to it? The old fan looks like it has the wires crimped in there somehow.

Alternatively, is it realistic to try to use the connector from the old fan? How do I remove it without damaging it?

Comment: Why not reuse the connector from old fan? Splice the new wires to the old wires

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a JST type connector. You could get cheap ones from ebay and such, or get real ones from your typical electronics retailers, digikey, jameco, etc. This is the plastic connector, the crimp terminal (the metal part), and an appropriate crimp tool. The crimp is held in place by plastic tabs (Looks like an E on the connector in your picture).

But for one off parts or project, just cut off the wire close to the old fan, and solder + heatshrink the new wires on. Simplest, cheapest route.

Comment: Real JST connectors are not that expensive, either. The shipping will be the most expensive part if you order from digikey or whatever.

Comment: Which JST connector line is it?

Comment: Can't say without measurement but ten bucks says its the typical fan connector, 3 pin XH